# Visual Studio cannot find CPPUNIT debugging database

Tags: visual-studio, cppunit

I am using Visual Studio 2008 with CPPUNIT. I already compiled CPPUNIT and added the CPPUNIT path to Include and Library path. Currently, I can compile my program with CPPUNIT library.

However, the linker generates the following warning:

> Warning   2   warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with
>   'C:\Program Files\cppunit\cppunit-1.12.1\lib\cppunitd.lib' or at
>   'c:\Users\hide1713\Desktop\3d_tank\cpp_pj\bin\vc90.pdb'; linking
>   object as if no debug info    cppunitd.lib    GameUnitTest

There's a cppunitd_dll.pdb file along with cppunitd.lib. How do I tell the linker where to find the CPPUNIT debug database?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

In your CppUnit project, be sure you have your compiler emitting a program database file that's compatible with your main project.  In the CppUnit project properties window, under the Config properties / C++ / General tree, you'll see the Debug Information Format box.  Select "Program Database /Zi" or whatever value exactly matches the same setting on your main project.  You'll then have to recompile them both, of course.